# While using Struts2 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, struts2

I am using struts2 to create a login application.
But when I run the program it gives a error like this.

`Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

My web.xml code

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SamStrut</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml code

```
<struts>

<package name ="a" extends = "struts-default">

<action name="verify" class= "com.test.LoginAction">

<result name = "success">/success.jsp</result>
<result name = "error">/error.jsp</result>

</action>
</package>

</struts>
```

Comment: What version of S2 (e.g., the `ng` package has been deprecated for awhile). What does the class look like? There's not enough information here to help yet. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: post your project structure. Check location of your struts.xml file. It has to be in src folder not inside package of your project. post your class code and how are you trying to create login system?. Try to follow this tutorial. http://java.candidjava.com/tutorial/Struts-2-simple-Login-example.htm  ping me if does not work.

Comment: Did you solve your login problem @Manoj M